# Xcode can distribute iOS app but altool doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode

I've made and distribute an iOS application from Xcode and have pushed it into Testflight.

Next, I try to do the same from the command-line.

```
xcodebuild -scheme QA -archivePath <path1> archive
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath <path1> -exportPath <path2> -exportOptionsPlist ExportOptions.plist
xcrun altool --upload-app -f <path2> -u ... -p ...
```

After this, I've had the error

```
2020-12-18 15:33:55.164 altool[78702:6031914] *** Error: Error uploading '<path2>'.
2020-12-18 15:33:55.166 altool[78702:6031914] *** Error: code -21017 (Unable to validate your application. Could not determine the package's bundle id. The package is missing an Info.plist or the CFBundlePackageType is not 'APPL' or 'FMWK'.)
```

info.plist contains

```
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
```

What have I do?

PS: ExportOptions.plist:

```
...
    <key>method</key>
    <string>app-store</string>
...
```

Comment: Try to open your archive and verify Info.plist inside.

Comment: I've done this. It's OK